# Variations of the transportation problem in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, discrete-optimization

The transportation problem is a famous problem in linear programming. For instance, 
http://www.utdallas.edu/~scniu/OPRE-6201/documents/TP1-Formulation.pdf
or 
http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/LP.pdf       Chapter 8

Some specific results are developed for this special linear programming problem.

I'm considering variations of this problem. The scenario is: you can only transfer from some supply points to some demand points (in other words, for each supply point, it cannot supply all the demand points; for each demond point, it cannot demand from all the supply points). Is there any existing paper/literature on this variation? I want to know if there are any specific results developed for this variation.

In other words, when we draw the bipartite graph (V1, V2), not every pair (one node in V1 and one node in V2) can reach each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the standard transportation problem with some of the costs being infinite.  In practice, any large number would qualify as infinite.